# Permissions for posting links to an open graph page via an administrating app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, publishing, facebook-page

I have several (hundreds) of pages that exist as nodes in the open graph.  All of these pages are administered by a single app.  I have no problem whatsoever posting to these pages' feeds (https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed) but when I attempt to post to the links feed:
(https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/links) I receive the following error:

> {"error":{"message":"(#282) Requires extended permission:
>   share_item","type":"OAuthException"}}

Since these pages are administered by my application, and are not users themselves, I do not know how to acquire extended permissions to share on the pages' behalf (also, from the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions) I believe I actually would want the "publish_stream" and/or "manage_pages" permissions, I do not see "share_item" listed).

So, my question then, is since pages cannot grant permissions to applications explicitly (not being alive), how do I perform actions that seem to require extended permissions on those pages via the administering application?

Or, put another way, how do I force a page to give me permissions to post shareable links to its wall?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A day of bashing on the Graph API led me to the solution.

Counterintuitively, I needed to grant MY OWN APPLICATION extended permissions to manage the pages, despite the fact that the application (not the user) is technically the administrator of these pages.  I'm guessing this has something to do with however Facebook maintains the relationship between the user who administers an app, and that apps' administration over the pages.

Regardless, while logged into Facebook as my application's administrator, I followed [Facebook's authentication guidelines](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication) and granted *myself* "offline_access", "publish_stream", and "manage_pages" permissions to my own application.  Not all of those may have been necessary, but I wanted to be sure.

I could then post to my pages' link streams as follows:

```
curl -F 'access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN' \ 
-F 'link=LINK' \ 
-F 'name=TITLE' \ 
-F 'description=DESCRIPTION' \ 
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/links
```

The new access token seems to grant sufficient permissions that no error is thrown and my links are properly formatted.